# Can Cat6 UTP stranded cable fit regular Cat6 Jacks?

Tags: ethernet, cable, rj-45, cat6

I have some stranded Cat6 UTP cable and want to use it to wire an Ethernet connection to a faceplate in a wall. Normally you use Solid rather than Stranded cable for this and I am concerned that the Jacks in the faceplate won't take the stranded cable or the connecting tools won't work properly.

Will it work? Or do I need to get special Jacks? Or is this just a big No No?

If I can't do this then could I just put RJ45 connectors on the end and use inline connectors?

Answer (score 5):

If the faceplate has punch-down contacts requiring a Krone tool you will need to use solid cable.  Stranded cable won't stay in place in this type of connector block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some punch-down jacks that have a piece of plastic that holds the wires in place, but I'm fairly certain it won't work as well as solid cable.

I'm not sure about using CAT6 cable in the plug, but I haven't had any problems with stranded CAT5e cable in a plug.